# Overloading operator-> in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a smart pointer class and I want to overload `operator->`; it's provided for convenience so I can access the members of the class contained inside the smart pointer directly.

I was looking at the way Boost implements this operator in its `shared_ptr` template. I noticed they added an assert checking if the pointer is indeed non-null before returning it. Currently, my operator returns the pointer without checking if it's null (essentially, a null pointer is undefined behavior in my current implementation). Should I add this assert as well?

(Also, how is this operator called? I couldn't find this on the web.)

Comment: Calling your own class "smart" anything is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Do you want undefined behaviour or not?  Its 100% your choice in the implementation.  I don't think anybody here can tell you whether you *should* or *should not* add such a feature.

Comment: @Tomalak That's what they're called -- smart pointers. I didn't make up the name. ;)

Comment: I know that's what they're called (by some people). It's still a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @Tomakal Assuming you're not joking... How can a name be a recipe for disaster? Is Boost also a disaster (see `boost/smart_ptr/`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's up to you. You could simply document that using it with a null pointer is undefined and do nothing, you could assert, you could throw an exception. There isn't a right answer. Personally, I would probably throw an exception.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I went with an assertion: if I end up trying to call a function through a null pointer it's going to be my fault as a programmer. (At least in my application, because there's no input the user can give that would call `operator->` on null.)

Answer (score 2):

> Should I add this assert as well?

If you're happy without it, then that's fine. **Just make sure it's documented**: that's the important thing.

> (Also, how is this operator called? I couldn't find this on the web.)

It doesn't really have a name. The standard just calls it "the `->` operator", also referring to it as "one of the class member access operators" (`[expr.const]`).

Wikipedia [lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++#Member_and_pointer_operators) it as "member b of object pointed to by a" (where, yes, other operators are given terse identifiers).

Comment: I usually just call it "the _other_ dereferencing operator". :-P

Comment: I call it the "arrow" operator.