# Is there a name for this: "->"

Tags: naming-conventions

This has popped up today and we don't know a single name for it. Ie. `$this->Session`

Comment: If you look for a precise name (as per some standard maybe) you should indicate the programming language you have in mind. The "canonical" name might differ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`The Arrow Operator`](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)

Comment: The definition: "The Arrow Operator" is really only useful within the context of L and RValues.  Consider how we might define the assignment operator "=" instead as the "two-lines operator."

Answer (score 1):

I will take a C or C++ perspective when answering this question, although the lack of `->` in languages like Java, seems to fit the definitions below well.

According to the [ANSI C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), **Section 6.5.2.3**: the "`->`" operator is defined as:

- "Structure/union pointer operator,"
- "Member access operator," (`.` and `->`),
- "Pointer operator,

Compare the `.` operator, which is defined in **Section 6.3.2.1**[1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) as the "Structure/union member operator." The member access operator -> is defined as one of a number of punctuators in **Section 6.4.6**[1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf):

"*A punctuator is a symbol that has independent syntactic and semantic signiﬁcance.
Depending on context, it may specify an operation to be performed (which in turn may
yield a value or a function designator, produce a side effect, or some combination thereof)
in which case it is known as an operator (other forms of operator also exist in some
contexts). An operand is an entity on which an operator acts.*"[1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)

See:
ISO/IEC 9899:TC3, Committee Draft — Septermber 7, 2007,  WG14/N1256
http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I would call it "arrow", but that's certainly subjective :)

Answer (score 0):

[C++ manual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Member_and_pointer_operators) names it as "Member b of object pointed to by a", so can it be *pointing operator*?

In PHP, it is called [object operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php).

Comment: Wikipedia is not a C++ manual. The C++ standard doesn't specifically name the operator.

Answer (score 0):

$this refers to the current module you are in and arrow sign is used for memory reference.
 [Check this for concept.](http://www.exforsys.com/tutorials/c-language/c-pointers.html) For php examples [refer here](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)

Comment: He's not asking what it does.

Comment: Fine. My apologies then. I was trying to help him although the mention of language used would have been of more help.

Answer (score 0):

How about this one: "Object Operator"

Answer (score 0):

This came up w.r.t. C++ as part of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297289/overloading-operator-in-c).

Really, the answer will completely depend on the language used, though some people use the term "arrow operator" as a visual cue, which can be language-agnostic.