# cast operator to pointer

Tags: c++, casting

I am defining a wrapper class that can be used as a drop-in replacement for the payload using the cast operator, however I run into a problem with pointer payload:

compiler (g++ 4.8.3) complains with:

error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘wrapper’
  w->a=3;

The implicit cast operator `wrapper::operator T&` is called for all pointer operations except dereference, is there something special about `->` operator?

```
struct pl{int a;};
struct wrapper{
    typedef pl* T;
    T t;
    operator T&(){return t;}    
};
int main(){
    wrapper w;
    w.t=new pl();
    (*w).a=1;//ok
    w[0].a=2;//ok
    w->a=3;//does not compile
    ++w;//ok
    if(w){}//ok
}
```

note: similar error with clang 3.3

Comment: The `->` operator has its own signature, you have to provide a T& operator->() to make it work.

Comment: You would have to pass `w` to a function expecting a `pl*`.

Answer (score 2):

You have been missing to declare/define a `operator->()` function for your class

```
struct pl{int a;};
struct wrapper{
    typedef pl* T;
    T t;
    operator T&(){return t;}    
    T& operator->() { return t; }  // << implement this function
};

int main(){
    wrapper w;
    w.t=new pl();
    (*w).a=1;//ok
    w[0].a=2;//ok
    w->a=3;//does not compile
    ++w;//ok
    if(w){}//ok
}
```

See ***[LIVE DEMO](http://ideone.com/HViqFR)***

Also see **[Overloading operator-> in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297289/overloading-operator-in-c)**

Comment: While this is a solution, it doesn't answer the question of why `operator T&()` was called for all the other cases when a pointer was needed while not for the case `w->a=3;`.

Comment: I don't have one at this time. I don't know how much digging is needed to explain the compiler behavior.